# Unexpected argument processing by MAIN()

Tags: command-line-arguments, raku

Scratching my head over this:

```
multi sub MAIN(Str:D $arg, Bool :$switch, *@the-rest) {
    say $arg;
    say $switch;
    say @the-rest;
}
```

When called with: `blah-command arg1 --switch`

It prints:

```
arg1
(Bool)
[--switch]
```

I expected:

```
arg1
True
```

What I'd ultimately like to do is this:

`blah-command arg1 --switch --unknown-stuff blah --more-unknown-stuff`

result in:

```
arg1
True
--unknown-stuff blah --more-unknown-stuff
```

Comment: You have to put named arguments before positional ones unless you set `%*SUB-MAIN-OPTS<named-anywhere>`. I think the doc is misleading. This looks like a suitable issue to add a comment to: github.com/Raku/doc/issues/2167. (Or maybe file a separate doc issue and/or PR.)